# Web scraping with R, XML Package - paths on web browser are different from parsed HTML download in R

Tags: xml, r, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping

I am web scraping [this website](http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/sao-paulo+sao-paulo/apartamento-padrao/aluguel/?rn=104123456&pag=1) (in portuguese).

When you are using google chrome, the xpath command `//div[@class='result-ofertas']//span[@class='location']/a[1]` correctly returns the neighborhood of the apartments for sale. You can try this yourself with Chrome's extension [xpath helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en).

Ok. So I try to download the website with R to automate the extraction of the data, with the `XML` package:

```
library(XML)    
site <- "http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/sao-paulo+sao-paulo/apartamento-padrao/aluguel/?rn=104123456&pag=1"
html.raw <- htmlTreeParse(site,useInternalNodes=T, encoding="UTF-8")
```

But when I download the website in R, the page source is not the same anymore.

The previous xpath command results in null:

```
xpathApply(html.raw, "//div[@class='result-ofertas']//span[@class='location']/a[1]", xmlValue)
```

But if you mannualy download the website to your computer instead of downloading it with R, the xpath above works just fine.

It seems that R is downloading another webpage (a "mobile" one, it is downloading [this one instead of the correct one](http://m.zapimoveis.com.br/imoveis/busca?TermoBusca=sao%20paulo%20sao%20paulo&Transacao=Locacao&SubTipoImovel=apartamento%20padrao&Pagina=1)), and not the one that it is shown in Chrome.

My problem is not with how to extract the information of this "different" page that R is downloading. I can actually deal with that with the xpath command below:

```
xpathApply(html.raw, "//p[@class='local']", xmlValue)
```

But I really would like to understand why and how this is happening.

More specifically:

1. What is happening here?
2. Why are the two different webpages (Chrome's and R's), even though the address is the same?
3. Is there a way to force R to download the exact webpage I see in Chrome (this would be useful, because I usually test the xpath commands with the *xpath helper* extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is most likely redirecting requests based on the user agent. Try setting the request user agent in R to match your Chrome user agent (which can be seen on the network tab of the developer tools. Just select a request and view the headers).

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, could you be more specific about where in chrome I can find the information and what command in R I have to write to ensure it will match the user agent? Thanks!

Comment: I have found the following: `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the `download.file()` function from the `utils` package. I first download the file to the HD and then parse it. It takes a long time though, this is not an optimal solution, and I am still not sure why this is happening. So if anyone else has another solution/answer...